# Why would the conference organizers ban the inclusion of new links (e.g. to datasets or repositories) in the text of the rebuttal?

Tags: peer-review, conference

Some conference organizers recently emailed authors who submitted a paper to the conference the following rebuttal policy change:

> 1. You are not allowed to include new links (e.g. to datasets or repositories) in the text of the rebuttal

Why would the conference organizers ban the inclusion of new links (e.g. to datasets or repositories) in the text of the rebuttal?

Comment: Ask them. Who else would know?

Comment: @Buffy People with experience in organizing conferences and/or peer-reviewing.

Answer (score 17):

The underlying reason might be that rebuttals should not present new data/results which were not included in the original submission.

Presenting new data/results in a rebuttal is problematic because it increases the review load: The new data might require some detailed explanations of how they were obtained and how they add to the overall work. Effectively, the reviewers have to discuss two versions of each paper (without and with the new results). The organizers might want to avoid that, given that the review load at good conferences is normally already quite substantial.

Of course, one could still allow links if they don't present new data/results. But this raises the question why these links were not included in the original paper. Potentially there have been previous experiences according to which the risk of misusing links to refer to new data/results is seen as too large.

Comment: As a bit of a variation on this, I could see the reason being that that the purpose of a rebuttal is to challenge the referees' interpretation or opinion of the paper *as originally presented*.  That's not so much about review load as about fairness to everyone, including competing submitters, though reducing review load is certainly another effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sure, but if all authors were allowed to add new results/data in order to address the rebuttal, that would be fair again then.

Comment: Sounds right. Updating data is a bit like moving the goal posts.

Answer (score 11):

It's usually to keep people from trying to ID reviewers by logging visitors to a private website. Same reason the NIH only allows links to one place, and that's a NCBI website they control.

Comment: Thank you, this is weird because 1) in that case, they should also ban links  in the original submission, which they don't 2) they could simply ask for links that don't allow users to log each others e.g. github repo/gdrive, as NIH did.

Comment: (1) is pretty common for some fields but infeasible for other fields and (2) is a logistical nightmare (gdrive is a problem for example - you can see who's viewing a document depending on the sharing settings, etc)

Comment: In which fields is it common to ban links in submissions?

Comment: It's a strict rule for submissions to the NIH and the NSF (with a couple of very specific exceptions). I've also had "don't click any links in this submission" as part of my reviewer guidelines for several journals, but I'm not aware of any journals that have outright prohibited them. (This is all in biology and related fields)

Comment: @lighthousekeeper (I also consider your answer to be at least equally probable and likely more probable)